# angular google maps double windows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I have an issue from angular google maps windows. I don't know why the windows label come double on the maps. I made in [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AdRewWsA7aPBnbBezcmZ?p=preview). I wan't to show all windows label, but it come it in double windows label. This is my HTML:

> ```
> <div id="map_canvas" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
>   <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options" bounds="map.bounds">
>     <ui-gmap-markers models="randomMarkers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" click="'onClick'">
>       <ui-gmap-windows show="show">
>         <div ng-non-bindable="">{{title}}</div>
>       </ui-gmap-windows>
>     </ui-gmap-markers>
>   </ui-gmap-google-map>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: Just a suggestion, create your own google maps directive. The api is simple to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `dorebuildall=true` to `ui-gmap-markers` element.

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6OehVgbWVUjrzCpcX833?p=preview)